# Accessing iOS Core Data from Android

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, core-data, data-storage

I developed a simple iPhone app by the book, using Core Data. The data is immutable and stored in a preloaded sqlite database, managed by Core Data.

Now I need to develop the (almost) same app for Android. I'm about to write a very basic set of classes that mimic Core Data, and read from the exact same sqlite database.

Before getting started on this, I was wondering if anyone knows about an Android library that does just this.

In theory, you could almost literally provide the same API as iOS does, maybe even parsing the object model as well.

Comment: Why try to mimic core data? Its best to use what the platform already provides? In Android case by using Shared Preferences and the SQLite DB

Comment: I will in fact use sqlite. The data is in a sqlite database. The format is that of Core Data, so I will be using its field names and such. But before embarking on this I'd like to make sure it hasn't been done before. Shared Preferences don't seem suitable for a (big) preloaded database.

Comment: @Ravi Vyas Actually SharedPreferences would be only good to save preferences and some limited amount of informations. You cannot expect sharedPreferences to be good enough to sql like data.

Comment: @Loïc Faure-Lacroix I agree , I was suggesting using a combination of both :-)

Comment: my bad, my eyes stopped to Shared Preferences didn't read sqlite DB...

Answer (score 7):

Core Data have its own data structure you can look at it and you will see something like this:

[image]

Tables from your model are prefixed by Z, so you can perfectly query this SQLite Database with SQL queries in Android.

Note: you can find this SQLite file after runnig your app with Simulator in the folder: `/Users/<you_name>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<ios_version>/Applications/<app_id>/Documents/<app_name>.sqlite`

Comment: There are exceptions, however, such as if you use parent entities in your data model. Then it is no longer as simple as using the Z prefix as the table structure it quite different that you may expect.

Answer (score 5):

In a more complex project, we used [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) as an replacement for Core Data when migrating code from iOS to Android. It does not come with visual modelling, but the basic operations quite similar. Being an ORM tool, greenDAO maps Java objects to SQLite and offers stuff like relations, too.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up writing a small core for android and wrote a small obj C routine to export java class definitions. Later I added full read/write support. Does greenDAO resemble core data close enough to make such an approach feasible?

Comment: It depends, of course... ;) greenDAO is a slim tool that cannot compete on with the breadth of features Core Data offers. For example, it lacks advanced stuff like change tracking, property validation, schema migration, etc. In the project, for example, the validation logic was done by additional Java code. Apart from that, greenDAO still gives a higher form of abstraction for working with SQLite, which still saves a big amount of work. You just persist objects and query for them. It won't close the gap to Core Data completely, but it's still better than doing all the SQL wiring by yourself.